# powershell convert xml to csv(or excel) by level format

Tags: xml, csv, azure-powershell

i have a xml file like this:

```
<a>
   <a.1>
      <data a.1></data a.1>
   </a.1>
</a>
```

I want to convert this xml to csv with this format:

```
Column1  | Column2 |  column3
<a>      |         |
         |  <a.1>  |
         |         |  <data a.1></data a.1>
         |  </a.1> |
</a>     |         |
```

Does anyone have any idea with this using powershell?

Answer (score 0):

We have created a sample xml file in our local environment with the below content.

```
<departments>  
<item>  
<deptid>100</deptid>  
<deptname>marketing</deptname>  
<employeecount>1000</employeecount>  
</item>  
</departments>
```

Using the below PowerShell cmdlets , we tried converting to csv it is working fine.

Here are the PowerShell Cmdlets:

```
[xml]$de=Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Downloads\depart.xml  
$de.departments.ChildNodes|Export-Csv C:\Users\Downloads\depart.csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter:","
```

Here is the sample output for reference:

[image]

Comment: I just want to push the node(open and close) to the second column, and also the child of its to 3rd column, the same for child-of-child to 4nd column